# Trying to print method, but it is giving error

Tags: scala

I am trying to print some attributes of employee along with method. but it is throwing and error.
But I am not able to understand this issue. can someone help to resolve the issue

**Error**

> Error:(12, 43) not found: value grossSalary
>       println("Employee gross salary is : "+grossSalary)

**Code**

```
case class EmployeeGross (empId: Int,empName: String, deptId: Int, var basicSalary: Double) {
  var Hra: Double= basicSalary*(30/100)
  var Da: Double = basicSalary*(10/100)
  var grossSalary: Double = basicSalary + Hra + Da
  def grossSalary(basicSalary: Double) = basicSalary + Hra + Da
  println("Employee salary information is :"+ empId,empName,deptId,basicSalary)
}

object EmployeeGross {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val Eg = new EmployeeGross(1,"test",10,1200.2)
     println("Employee gross salary is : "+ grossSalary)
  }
}
```

Comment: `30/100` is integer division and equals zero. Multiply by `0.3`, which is a `Double`, to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `grossSalary` from the `EmployeeGross` object, probably thinking that this object knows which employee you have in mind. This is not possible to know, you have to use `Eg.grossSalary`.

Furthermore, you need to multiply by `0.3` and `0.1` rather than `10/100` and `30/100`. This is because `10/100` performs *integer division*, which will yield 0. You could also fix this by writing `10.0/100` which will do floating point division.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying compute grosssalary with the the help of basicsalary+hra+da. But still I am seeing output of grosssalary as basicSalary (i.e 1356).

Comment: basicSalary*(30/100) whatever the value is suppose tobe calculate with in parathesis is not calculated properly. Is there anyother way to claculate this basicSalary*0.3//(30/100). can some one suggest

Comment: got the solution. Thanks